# Saving StringVars to text and problems with globals

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, global-variables

This is my first project with tkinter and I'm having some problems with StringVars. I am trying to create a program where a user can input information and then it will save it to a txt document, the simplified code is.

```
def New_Condition():

    def Global_Vars():
        global Str_Name
        Str_Name = StringVar()
        global Str_Eff
        Str_Eff = StringVar()

    Global_Vars()
    Gui = Tk()

    def Save_Condition():
        CND_InfoList = [StringVar.get(Str_Name),StringVar.get(Str_Eff)]
        TXT_CND = open("C:\\Users\\Clark\\DnD\\Conditiontxt\\Conditions.txt","a")
        TXT_CND.write("$".join(CND_Info_List) + "$\n")
        TXT_CND.close()

    Name = Entry(textvariable = Str_Name).pack()
    Eff =  Entry(textvariable = Str_Eff).pack()
    Save = Button(text = "Save",command = Save_Condition).pack()

    Gui.mainloop()
```

The program will save to a textfile but it only saves blanks and not the user input in the entry boxes.

I'm not sure if the error is with the way I'm declaring global variables or if it is with the StringVar itself. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code is pretty messy, I hope that's caused by trying to simplify it. First of all, it creates the `StringVar`s before calling `Tk()`, which can't be done. Then in the `Save_Condition` function you define `List` but then you try to join `CND_Info_List` when writing to the file. Shouldn't this be `List`?

Comment: Yh, all caused by simplification. Tk had already been called but I am calling it twice for different screens. Will the second Tk() need to be called before defining aswell. Also the list is a Typo, I'll edit it

Comment: Damn, feel like an idiot. I forgot to say which which window the StringVars are assigned to, just needed to put Gui in the brackets

Comment: @sircwh: you must call `Tk` before creating the `StringVar`s, and you should only ever call `Tk` exactly once. Calling it more than once _will_ cause unexpected problems.

Comment: So how can you create multiple windows. I thought that Tk() just created a new window however I need a limitless amount of windows

Comment: Use a [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) window.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is that you're creating the instances of `StringVar` before creating the instance of `Tk`. You must always initialize tkinter before creating widgets or `StringVar`s.  When I move `Gui = Tk()` before creating the `StringVar`, your code works.

According to some comments to your original question, you say you are creating multiple instances of `Tk`. This can also cause unexpected problems. If you need to create additional windows you need to be creating instances of `Toplevel` rather than `Tk`. Your program should always have exactly once instance of `Tk`, and it needs to be created before any other Tkinter objects.